# bash: ~ expansion inside shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I tried to write up a simple shell script to build a pipeline for analysis and one step involves building a symlink to existing directories and files.

Initially I set up like this:

```
dir='~/project/xxxx/'
ln -s $dir .
```

However, the above code didn't work.

I figured it out that the ~ didn't get expanded inside the shell script when it's executed.

I tried to use double quote instead of single quote around the directory path but that didn't work either.

The following worked

```
dir="$HOME/project/xxxx/"
ln -s $dir .
```

I'm just wondering why the ~ didn't work. What's the formal name for this phenomenon?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tilde expansion does not occur inside quotes of any kind.  So, for example, use instead:

```
dir=~'/project/xxxx/'
```

Note also that if you use the `~username/` format, the `username/` part must also be unquoted.  From `man bash`:

> Tilde Expansion
>
> ```
>    If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (`~'),  all  of
>    the characters preceding the first unquoted slash (or all charac‐
>    ters, if there is no unquoted slash) are considered a  tilde-pre‐
>    fix.   If  none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted,
>    the characters  in  the  tilde-prefix  following  the  tilde  are
>    treated as a possible login name.  If this login name is the null
>    string, the tilde is replaced with the value of the shell parame‐
>    ter  HOME.  If HOME is unset, the home directory of the user exe‐
>    cuting the shell is substituted instead.  Otherwise,  the  tilde-
>    prefix  is  replaced  with the home directory associated with the
>    specified login name.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
I figured it out that the ~ didn't get expanded inside the shell script when it's executed.
```

Not true, it doesn't get expanded in *single quotes*.

```
The following worked `dir='$HOME/project/xxxx/'`
```

That's a lie, it doesn't get expanded either.

Use `~` without quotes, or use `$HOME` without quotes / in double quotes.

Remember, you can concatenate strings with various quotations:

```
echo a"b"'c'
abc
```

Move out `~` from the path if that helps readability.

My suggestion: prefer `$HOME`.

Comment: +1 for using `$HOME` instead. `~` is more of an alias to reduce typing than a reliable constructor for home directories.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the tilde out of the quotes: `dir=~/'project/xxxx/'`